# Navigation menu in umbraco

Tags: asp.net, xslt, content-management-system, umbraco

I am using umbraco cms. here i have a problem in navigation menu for multilingual site. my xslt files code is given below. it only renders menu in english. i am new to umbraco. so can any one please tell me that where i have to change in this code to make it work correct according to different languages. my code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets ">


  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
  <xsl:variable name="rootPage" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::root"/>
    <xsl:variable name="siteRoot" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@level = 1]" />
  <xsl:variable name="propertyAlias" select="/macro/PropertyAlias"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="homepage" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::Homepage"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nodeIds" select="umbraco.library:Split($homepage/*[name()=$propertyAlias],',')" />


      <ul class="navigation fc">
        <xsl:for-each select="$nodeIds/value">
        <xsl:variable name="linkNone" select="$rootPage//*[@isDoc][@id = string(current()/.)]"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($linkNone/@id)> 0">
        <li>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
              <xsl:if test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@level &gt; 1]/@id = $linkNone/@id">
            <xsl:text>selected</xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <xsl:text> last</xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>

            </xsl:attribute>

          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($linkNone/umbracoUrlAlias) > 0">
              <a href="{$linkNone/umbracoUrlAlias}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$linkNone/@nodeName"/>
              </a>
              <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>              
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl($linkNone/@id)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$linkNone/@nodeName"/>
              </a>
              <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>      
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>

        </li>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>

      </ul>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>​
```

Comment: What does 'work correctly' means in this context? What does not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the $rootPage ever.  For multilingual or multisite you want to stop at the home page above the current content ($siteRoot).

It looks like your navigation is selected by a picker on the home page.  Any reason why you don't just let the content tree structure determine the navigation?  May be simpler in this case.

If this doesn't help, please post your content tree structure example.